# Animate as a sea wave the top of a block

Tags: html, css, animation, particles

I'd like to animate the top of a `div` which is filled with a blue sea like color.

And I'd like the animation to feint little sea waves. Knowing that my displaying is for a very little resolution (120px width).

I tried with particles-js, and it was cool to learn how to add a motion effect, but it doesn't make my top section looking like sea waves.

And then I tried with CSS, trying to understand some existing code and the best I've done for the moment is that:

```css
:root {
  --bg-color: #dfffa9;
  --wave-color: #0048ff;
  --animation-time: 4s;
  --max-height: 15px;
  --circle-offset: -1.5%;
  --wave-width: 55%;
  --height-wave-up: 109%;
  --height-wave-down: 100%;
  --top-wave-up: 60%;
  --top-wave-down: 40%;
  --border-radius-right-up: 100% 50%;
  --border-radius-left-up: 50% 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: var(--wave-color);

}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 10vh;
  background: var(--bg-color);
}

.wave {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--max-height);
  background: var(--bg-color);
  animation: beWavy var(--animation-time) infinite linear;
}

.wave::before,
.wave::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: var(--border-radius-right-up);
  width: var(--wave-width);
}

.wave::before {
  height: var(--height-wave-up);
  background-color: var(--wave-color);
  right: var(--circle-offset);
  top: var(--top-wave-up);
  animation: beWavyBefore var(--animation-time) infinite step-end;
}

.wave::after {
  height: var(--height-wave-down);
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  left: var(--circle-offset);
  top: var(--top-wave-down);
  animation: beWavyAfter var(--animation-time) infinite step-end;
}

@keyframes beWavy {
  0% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    height: var(--max-height);
  }
  25% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    height: var(--max-height);
  }
  75% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    height: 0;
  }
  100% {
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    height: var(--max-height);
  }
}

@keyframes beWavyBefore {
  25% {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    height: var(--height-wave-down);
    top: var(--top-wave-down);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-left-up);
  }
  75% {
    background-color: var(--wave-color);
    height: var(--height-wave-up);
    top: var(--top-wave-up);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-right-up);
  }
}

@keyframes beWavyAfter {
  25% {
    background-color: var(--wave-color);
    height: var(--height-wave-up);
    top: var(--top-wave-up);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-left-up);
  }
  75% {
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    height: var(--height-wave-down);
    top: var(--top-wave-down);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-right-up);
  }
}
```

```html
<?php

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Sea level</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body>



  <section class="container">

    <div class="wave"></div>

  </section>
```

But 2 waves only seems really repetitve and low cost haha. I want random waves with random starting points.
So if someone could help me understand how it works exactly, thanks.